# accesing function of an object stored in vector

Tags: c++, objective-c, object, inheritance

If I would have an object that is basically a vector container looking like this:

```
std::vector<Base*> programs; //let's say in header file vector container would be defined like this

Box::box{
Base * a = new derived1(100);
Base * b = new derived2(100);
programs.push_back(a);
programs.push_back(b);
};//and it goes on, etc.
```

and when i create in main:

```
Box *ptr = new Box;
```

Then i wonder how can i access a public function that is a member of, let's say class derived1? Is it even possible?

Comment: This has nothing to do with vectors, or `Box`.

Comment: Check out virtual functions and polymorphism.

Comment: I wondered if there is a solution apart from virtual functions, because for example what if a dervied1 has one attribute, derived2 would have two attributes and i'd like to activate a function that returns the value of attributes? I mean, i can't return two values at once in one function, no?

Comment: If you know the type of the object you can cast it, e.g. `static_cast<derived1*>(programs[0])->Function()` but you have to be sure of the type. Better to use polymorphism.

Comment: Oh :) It was exactly what i wanted to find, thank you for help